# Can someone help me with a logic problem in Godot?

Tags: godot, gdscript

I'm having a problem trying to get a timer to start in Godot whenever I press the F key. I've double checked to make sure I'm following the tutorial I found properly but it still won't start the timer whenever I press the F key.

```
extends State

@export var return_state:State
@export var attack1_name:String = "attack1"
@export var attack2_name:String = "attack2"
@export var attack2_node:String = "attack2"
@export var return_anim_node:String = "move"
@export var timer:Timer

#func _ready():
#   timer.start()
    

func state_inpute(event:InputEvent):
    if(event.is_action_pressed("attack")):
        timer.start()
        
func _on_animation_tree_animation_finished(anim_name):
    if(anim_name == attack1_name):
        if(timer.is_stopped()):
            next_state = return_state
            playback.travel(return_anim_node)
        else :
            playback.travel(attack2_node)
    if(anim_name == attack2_name):
        next_state = return_state
        playback.travel(return_anim_node)
```

So far I'm trying to get my Attack State script to start a 0.2 second timer whenever the F key is pressed (which is assigned to the "attack" event) For some reason whenever I press the "attack" key the attack animation plays but immediately goes back to the "Idle" state without letting me press F again which should let me trigger a follow up attack as long as the timer Im trying to start hasn't reached 0.

I've double checked that I've assigned the right Timer object to the script along with putting a label over the player character to show the timer. When I start the timer in the same script in the _ready function it briefly shows the timer counting down before it reaches 0. But I only want the timer to start whenever the player presses the F key.

Comment: Based on the code snippet and the behavior you've described, it seems like the main issue is related to the state_inpute function .

Comment: I'm stupid. Apparently I spelt "input" wrong so It has to be "func state_input" instead of func state_inpute